# I am trying to make a batch file to replace text in itself and other files

Tags: batch-file, replace

I am trying to make a batch file to change the resolution of fortnite.

I have this file and I need to make it:

- Work from any folder.
- Replace the value with the updated value after it changes.
- Save it after the file closes.

Here is my code:

```bash
Echo off

set "textfile=GameUserSettings.ini"
set "tempfile=GameUserSettingsTemp.ini"

echo First Number Resolution
set /p replace1=

echo Second Number Resolution
set /p replace2=

(for /f "delims=" %%i in (%textfile%) do (
        set "line=%%i"
        setlocal enabledelayedexpansion
        set "line=!line:1280=%replace1%!"
        echo(!line!
        endlocal
))>"%tempfile%"

(for /f "delims=" %%i in (%textfile%) do (
        set "line=%%i"
        setlocal enabledelayedexpansion
        set "line=!line:1024=%replace2%!"
        echo(!line!
        endlocal
))>"%tempfile%"

(for /f "delims=" %%i in (StretchRes.bat) do (
        set "line=%%i"
        setlocal enabledelayedexpansion
        set "line=!line:1280=%replace1%!"
        echo(!line!
        endlocal
))>"TempRes.bat"

(for /f "delims=" %%i in (StretchRes.bat) do (
        set "line=%%i"
        setlocal enabledelayedexpansion
        set "line=!line:1024=%replace2%!"
        echo(!line!
        endlocal
))>"TempRes.bat"

del %textfile%
rename %tempfile%  %textfile%
del StretchRes.bat
rename TempRes.bat  StretchRes.bat
```

I tried looking through StackOverflow for the replacing part, but couldn't find it.

Comment: Your second replacement is overwriting all modifications from your first replacement. If you want to run from any directory, change the values of both textfile and tempfile to use fully qualified absolute paths. Doublequote the files in your last four lines and the parenthesized source files in your for loops, and include the `UseBackQ` instruction too. e.g. ```(For /F UseBackQ^ Delims^=^ EOL^= %%i In ("%textfile%") Do (```. I also added an `EOL` option, because the default `For /F` command ignores all lines which begin with a semicolon, this defines that 'begin' character as nothing.

Answer (score 0):

```
@ECHO OFF
SETLOCAL

set "textfile=GameUserSettings.ini"
set "tempfile=GameUserSettingsTemp.ini"

echo First Number Resolution
SET "replace1="
set /p replace1=

echo Second Number Resolution
SET "replace2="
set /p replace2=

(for /f "delims=" %%i in (%textfile%) do (
        set "line=%%i"
        setlocal enabledelayedexpansion
        set "line=!line:1280=%replace1%!"
        set "line=!line:1024=%replace2%!"
        echo(!line!
        endlocal
))>"%tempfile%"

(for /f "delims=" %%i in (StretchRes.bat) do (
        set "line=%%i"
        setlocal enabledelayedexpansion
        set "line=!line:1280=%replace1%!"
        set "line=!line:1024=%replace2%!"
        echo(!line!
        endlocal
))>"TempRes.bat"


move "%tempfile%" "%textfile%"
move "TempRes.bat" "StretchRes.bat"
GOTO :EOF
```

**Always verify against a test directory before applying to real data.**

***[untested]***

The `@` before `echo off` prevents the `echo off` being listed to the console.

The `setlocal` keeps the environment clean. Without it, any changes to the environment (like setting a variable) will be retained until explicitly removed.

`sett`ing a variable before a `set/p` will set the value to be used for the variable if the user simply presses <kbd>Enter</kbd>. Note that if the user simply presses <kbd>Enter</kbd> then the variable will remain unchanged, not set to *empty*.

It's quite kosher to apply two replacements in succession. Note that if `replace1` is `1024` then it will be replaced by `replace2`. You could fix this with

```
    set "line=!line:1280=%replace1%!"
    if "%replace1%" neq "1024" set "line=!line:1024=%replace2%!"
```

`move` will overwrite the destination file if it exists, so `del...ren` is not required.

`move` will generate a message reporting the move. You can suppress that message by appending `>nul`.

To run from anywhere, display your `path` with the command `path`, and put you batch in any of the directories listed. It's common for batchers to create a separate directory called `batch` or even `belfry` to store batches. So long as the directory containing your batch is on the `path`, you should be able to run from anywhere. As your batch uses the current directory for the files, just navigate there and run *yourbatchname*.

Note that this routine is untested. Use caution.